# Possible to show a picture on a JTextArea?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, server

So now i'm coming to the end of the project. So I have coded so I know my send a picture function does work. The only problem that I need to solve is that I have a JTextArea for my Chat client and I want to a picture (When you are sending a picture) to be shown here. Is that possible to do?

**JTextarea:**

```
textareamessage = new JTextArea(
                "Welcome to the #BallIsLife Chat room.\n");
        textareamessage.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textareamessage.setLineWrap(true);
        textareamessage.setEditable(false);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textareamessage);
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane);
        getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I dont know if its needed more code for it. If yes. Just tell me what you need to know :)

Comment: No, not really, but you can use a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane`

Comment: As for a "chat" client, you could cheat and use a `JList` or `JTable`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok So I tried to do JTextPane and got it all worked until I needed to somehow get

public void append(String str) {
  textareamessage.append(str);
 }

To work

Comment: Personally, I'd not use a text component for this, but if was, I'd explore `JEditorPane` and look into using `HTML`.  You might have better luck interacting directly with the `StyledDocument`, things like `insertString` and the like

Comment: A [possible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188986/java-swing-how-do-i-create-a-jtextpane-with-multiple-icons-on-the-same-line/22189237#22189237)

Answer (score 0):

I think a JTextPane would suit your needs better:

reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: Nice comment, got a runnable example which solves the OP's problem?

Comment: link is having JPane example @MadProgrammer

Comment: Still is only comment ;) [*"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (and no, I didn't see an example which would solve the OP's on amongst the tutorial)

Comment: you are right @MadProgrammer since Thrill have posted some part of code which is not enough to solve the problem by giving some relevant code snippet, I give that link.

Comment: *"Is not enough to solve the problem"* - Then why post an answer?! It should have been a comment!