# Insert a picture into a JTextPane when click button

Tags: java

```
button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) textPane1.getDocument();

            Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
            StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon("emoticons_01_32.png"));

            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "ignored text", style);
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

In my notepad application, I am trying to add an image in JtextPane when button is clicking

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: nothing happens in the JtextPane

Comment: Tried repainting?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to use a "style" for this, but instead, simply "insert" the icon into the document, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188986/java-swing-how-do-i-create-a-jtextpane-with-multiple-icons-on-the-same-line/22189237#22189237)

Comment: now it's to same

Comment: public void mouseClicked(MouseE vent e){  textPanel.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("emoticons_02_32.png)); }     i don't know were is problem ??